# output inside foreach by serialize, store in database

Tags: php, serialization, foreach

how can output of inside foreach with serialize store in database? next: called of database?

please give me example.

```
foreach($upload_data as $file) {
    echo serialize($file['file']);
}
output: s:54:"Chrysanthemum6.jpg";s:47:"/Desert6.jpg";
```

With respect

Comment: Can you please extend your question a bit? I have problems to understand what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$result = array();
foreach ($upload_data as $file) {
  $result[] = $file['file'];
}
var_dump(serialize($result));
```

Answer (score 0):

store the serialize in a variable?

```
$result = '';
foreach($upload_data as $file) {
  $result .= serialize($file['file'];
}
echo $result;
```

Comment: Don't know, if this is part of the question, but your code will produce invalid serialized data `var_dump(unserialize(serialize('file1') . serialize('file2')));
// string(5) "file1"`